# Declaring a Hash as a Constant with a default value in Ruby in one line

Tags: ruby, hash

My goal is to use a Hash with a default value as a class constant. To do this it seems to me that I must initialise a Hash in one line as a constant with pre-defined value and a default value.

According to the Ruby documentation, I can set a default value in two way :

- In the constructor then by adding value as follow :

  ```
  MY_HASH = Hash.new(-1)
  MY_HASH[1] = 0
  MY_HASH[2] = 42
  ```
- By adding values first then setting the default value later :

  ```
  MY_HASH = {
      1=>0,
      2=>42,
  }
  MY_HASH.default = -1
  ```

I tried to do it in one line like this, but it does not work :

```
    MY_HASH = {
        1=>0,
        2=>42,
    }.default = -1

   #It's the same as :
   MY_HASH = -1
```

Is there a way to declare a Hash with a default value in one line ?

Comment: Pierre, I have no objection to the answer you selected. I would have made the same choice (and would have given that answer had it been available). However, you made that selection after less than twenty minutes of posting the question. I suggest that in future you hold off making a selection for awhile, lest you discourage other answers or short-circuit others who are still working on answers. Many here wait at least a couple of hours before awarding the greenie.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `update`:

```
MY_HASH = Hash.new(-1).update(1 => 0, 2 => 42)
MY_HASH[1]
#=> 0
MY_HASH[52]
#=> -1
```

Or you can use `Hash#merge`.

Answer (score 11):

Here are two other solutions.

```
MY_HASH = { 1=>0, 2=>42 }.tap { |h| h.default = -1 }
```

```
MY_HASH[1]      #=> 0
MY_HASH[529326] #=> -1
```

---

```
MY_HASH = ->(key) { { 1=>0, 2=>42 }.fetch(key, -1) }
```

```
MY_HASH[1]      #=>  0
MY_HASH[529326] #=> -1
```